# How do I merge these two varnish backends?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, thumbor

I am using thumbor and s3.

I want to use varnish infront of them.

I know how to do place varnish in each of them but I can't combine the two

**varnish setup for thumbor**

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;

backend thumbor1 { .host ="127.0.0.1"; .port="8888";  .max_connections = 200; .connect_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout  = 5s; }
# backend thumbor2 { .host ="127.0.0.1"; .port="9002";  .max_connections = 200; .connect_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout  = 5s; }

acl internal {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new vdir = directors.round_robin();
    vdir.add_backend(thumbor1);
#     vdir.add_backend(thumbor2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend();
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
         if (!client.ip ~ internal) {
            return (synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
         }
         return (purge);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

**varnish setup for s3**

```
 vcl 4.0;


 backend default
 {
   .host = "my.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com";
   .port = "80";
 }

 sub vcl_backend_fetch
 {
   set bereq.http.Host = "my.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com";
   set bereq.http.Date = now;

 }
```

I'd like the final result would be something like

```
client => varnish => thumbor => s3 (thumbnail image)
client => varnish => s3 (normal image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put 2 backend blocks in the one file. Then in the vcl_recv you should set which backend do you want by some header, url path etc.

To set which backend to use, you could use:

```
set req.backend_hint = thumbor1;
# Or
set req.backend_hint = default;
```

There you could find how I've applied it to use 2 backends - localhost:3000 & localhost:8080: https://github.com/new-fantastic/vsf-cache-varnish/blob/master/docker/varnish/shared.vcl